# Accessing SharePoint On Premise through Internet

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 deployed on premise.
I want to access this sharepoint outside the premise through internet.
How do I do it?

Thank you.
Toniks

Comment: Did you really mean that you want to perform administrative tasks on your SharePoint server from outside the organization over the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that you just "do" I am afraid.  What you are talking about doing is creating an extranet within SharePoint.  There is all kinds of security analysis, system configuration, content requirements that you have to do.  [Here's a good place to start](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635878.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  However, I strongly suggest you look into bringing someone in that has experience with this.  Why?  Because you are talking about exposing your internal SharePoint environment with all of your documents and your data to the outside world.  This is NOT something you want to take the chance of mistakes on.